# Find and replace acronyms by full province names in SAS

Tags: string, replace, sas

I need to replace a string in a SAS dataset in the following way :

- `OTTAWA ON` should be replaced with `OTTAWA ONTARIO`
- `WHATEVER QC` should be replaced with `WHATEVER QUEBEC`

etc.
However, `HOUSE ON THE HILL` should not become `HOUSE ONTARIO THE HILL`.

That is, I want to replace all instances of `ON` with `ONTARIO` but only if `ON` exists as the last word in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to do this. From what you have described, I think the following should work.

```
myString = prxchange("s/(.*)( ON)$/$1 ONTARIO/",-1,strip(myString));
myString = prxchange("s/(.*)( QC)$/$1 QUEBEC/",-1,strip(myString));
```

Comment: Correct and efficient, but if you want to generalise it, using a translation data set, like Richard and I did, you will need to be creative.

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate control data set to maintain the substitutions (postal code -> province) you want.

- Load the control data into a hash
- Process the data scanning out the last 'word'
- If the word is a key in the hash then replace the word with the province value.

Presuming you are only performing transformations for a 'token' (CA postal code) as the final 'word' an example of the control data, data and transformation is as follows:

```
data O_Canada(label="Our home and native land");
length postal $2 province $26 ;
input postal& province&;     * suffix & means data fields separated by >1 space;
datalines;
ON  Ontario
QC  Quebec
NS  Nova Scotia
NB  New Brunswick
MB  Manitoba
BC  British Columbia
PE  Prince Edward Island
SK  Saskatchewan
AB  Alberta
NL  Newfoundland and Labrador
;

data cities(label='Some popular places');
length place $100;
input place $CHAR50.;
datalines;
CALGARY AB
VANCOUVER BC
WINNIPEG MB
MONCTON NB
ST. JONHS NL
HALIFAX NS
TORONTO ON
MONTREAL QC
SAKATOON SK
CHARLOTTETOWN PE
WHITEHORSE YT
YELLOWKNIFE NT
IQALUIT NU
GOLDMINE YUKON
;

data cities;
  modify cities;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    length postal $3 province $26;  * postal 1 bigger so scanned postal will not always match;
    declare hash provinces(dataset:'O_Canada');
    provinces.defineKey('postal');
    provinces.defineData('province');
    provinces.defineDone();
    call missing(postal, province);
    drop postal province;
  end;

  postal = scan(place,-1,' ');
  if provinces.find() eq 0 then do;

    * this inline replacement presumes all postal codes are 2 characters;
    * -1 from length will replace starting from found postal;
    
    substr(place,length(place)-1) = province;  * inline replacement;

    replace;
  end; 
run;
```

Result
[image]

Comment: For large volumes, this is the best, fastest solution indeed. For smaller ones mine is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

`scan(myString, -1)` returns the last word in `myString` and `trim(myString)` removes trailing blanks, so in a data step this does the job:

```
cutString = substr(myString, length(myString) - 2);
select scan(myString, -1) 
    when 'ON' myString = cutString || 'ONTARIO';
    when 'QC' myString = cutString || 'QUEBEC';
end;
```

or in SQL

```
select case scan(myString, -1) 
            when 'ON' then trim(myString) || 'TARIO' 
            when 'QC' then substr(myString, length() - 2) || 'QUEBEC'
            else myString end as myString 
from YOU_KNOW_BETTER_THAN_I_DO;
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but I should have been more clear, I also have others that I have to change for example if it is QC I need to make it QUEBEC so concatenating won't work

Comment: Indeed, you should have been more clear in the first place!

Comment: You had better indicated if you work in a data step or proc sql too.

Comment: I'm indifferent to a data step vs. a proc sql step.

Answer (score 0):

```
data GEOGRAPHY;
  file datalines truncover;
  informat geo $2. graphy $32.;
  input geo $ graphy $;
  datalines;
ON ONTARIO
QC QUEBEC
;
proc sql;
  select whatever_you_want, 
         case graphy 
              when '' then myString
              else substr(myString, length(myString) - length(geo)) || graphy 
         end as myString
  from HAVE left joion GEOGRAPHY on scan(myString, -1) eq geo;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sonny, I think the regular expression is very good. And @astel, there is another easy understading way:

```
data test;
  InText = 'HOUSE ON THE HILL';
  output;
  InText = 'OTTAWA ON';
  output;
run;

data _null_;
  set test;

  if cats(reverse(InText)) =: 'NO ' then OutText = tranwrd(InText,' ON',' ONTARIO');
  put Intext = @30 OutText = ;
run;
```

The output will be

```
InText=HOUSE ON THE HILL     OutText=
InText=OTTAWA ON             OutText=OTTAWA ONTARIO
```

Reverse the variable so you can easily judge if the new variable is start with `NO` , that means the raw variable is end with  `ON`. Then do the replace work by using a `tranwrd()` funtion.

Comment: You need to trim value passed to REVERSE() to prevent the trailing spaces in the input value from becoming leading spaces in the result.

Comment: Yes, this is why I add `cats()` here.

Comment: CATS() will remove both leading and trailing spaces, but since your comparison operator does not care that the former leading spaces have also been removed it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Note this does not properly handle cases that end with `' ON'` but also have `' ON'` earlier in the string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Tom. Yes that is important because I do not want HOUSE ON THE HILL ON to become HOUSE ONTARIO THE HILL ONTARIO